# Python : print 1-1000000 with recursion

Tags: python, recursion

This code results in `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object` .
I know it is very easy to use loop but is there any way to implement it using recursion without increasing recursion limit?
Tail call optimization is one method? Are there any other methods?

```
def print_recursion(m,n):
    if m==n:
        return
    else:
        print_recursion(m+1,n)

print_recursion(1,1000000)
```

Comment: You *can* do it by implementing tail call optimization yourself.  (But don't, just use a loop.)  See linked dupe.

Comment: As @Samwise said, in practice you should be using a loop rather than recursion. However, if you are determined to use recursion I think divide & conquer is a better choice than faking tail call optimization with exception catching.

Comment: @pjs can you give me your code. I am new to recursion.

Comment: @pjs : I have just implemented it and it works but the run time for  1-1000000 is about one minutes. I wonder why your laptop run too fast.

Comment: Mine is Ryzen 5600G with 32GB of Ram. Thank you for helping me to learn a new thing!

Comment: The question includes an answer, which makes it very unclear what's being asked.

Comment: @PaulHankin The question was closed as a duplicate. OP added the answer based on comments I gave while it was closed. Once things were re-opened, I posted my answer and rolled back the question to not include the answer. You can check the edit log, although I've since deleted the comments containing my "answer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a divide and conquer strategy. Treat the problem like in-order traversal of a binary tree where conceptually each node contains a range. The root contains the full range, and each descendent node contains half the range of its parent. You print the current value when the lower_limit of the range equals the upper_limit. Otherwise, calculate the midpoint of the range and make two recursive calls to the subranges (lower_limit, midpoint) and (midpoint + 1, upper_limit). This cuts the problem in half at each level of the recursion, so the recursive stack size is O(log(N)) where N is the original range length. For a range of 1_000_000 the tree's height is 20.

The code is:

```python
def print_recursion(lower_limit, upper_limit):
    if lower_limit == upper_limit:
        print(lower_limit)
    else:
        midpoint = lower_limit + (upper_limit - lower_limit) // 2
        print_recursion(lower_limit, midpoint)
        print_recursion(midpoint + 1, upper_limit)

print_recursion(1, 1000000)
```

I tested it with smaller ranges to confirm it works as it should, then ran a timing for the full range:

```text
% time python3 rec.py | wc       
 1000000 1000000 6888896
python3 rec.py  0.32s user 0.01s system 95% cpu 0.343 total
wc  0.01s user 0.00s system 4% cpu 0.333 total
%
```

As you can see, the Python portion of this runs in about 1/3 of a second. This is using Python 3.10.8 on M1 MacBook Pro. Word count (`wc`) confirms that there were a million lines.

In practice you should just do this with a loop as Samwise said in their comment, but if you insist on recursion and are dealing with large ranges this approach is simple, readable, and maintainable in my opinion.